# SQL server CA certificate for column level encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, certificate

Can you use a CA certificate with column level encryption for sql server? So far i have only seen examples of self-signed certs.

Comment: In most cases that wouldn't really make much sense. CA certificates are typically only used for signing other certificates.

Comment: I don't think there is much point doing so. No verification is done on the certificate. I assume you are referring to the cert which encrypts the DEK, as the DEK itself is not something that is issued by a CA anyway.